# Return JavaScript into a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, element

How is it possible to return a string from a JavaScript Code into a HTML attribute like in the following example?

```
<div class="xx" animation="yy" animate-duration="<spript>Code goes here<script>" ...>
</div>
```

I can not get it right, is there a solution?

Comment: have you tried element.setAttribute()?

Comment: no, how would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your example will work because the script tags will only be treated as a string. I suggest you use `Element.setAttribute(attribute name, attribute value)` if you only want to set the attribute of the element.

```
<div class="xx"></div>
<script>document.querySelector(".xx").setAttribute("animate-duration", "value");</script>
```

See the following for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="xx" id="id1" animation="yy"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("id1").setAttribute("animate-duration", "your value");
</script>
```

The `id` of the above `<div>` tag is `id1`. So `document.getElementById("id1").setAttribute("animate-duration", "your value");` selects the `<div>` tag and sets it's `animate-duration` value to whatever you set.